# binding path in silverlight treeview

Tags: silverlight, binding, treeview

my binded treeview work fine with string property but not with a "property of another property".

My code:

```
Public class A
    Public data as string
End Class

Public Class T
    Public o As A
    Public ReadOnly Property desc As String
        Get
            Return o.data
        End Get
    End Property
    Property children As New ObservableCollection(Of T)()
End Class
```

xaml that work:

```
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=children}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=desc}" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

xaml that not work:

```
    <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=children}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=o.data}" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

What is the mistake?
thanks.

Comment: A.data isn't a property, if I understand the vb syntax correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to properties in silverlight. Your o is not a property at the moment, you need to define setters and getters.

I'm not familiar with vb so I'm not sure what the correct syntax is. Either define it as a property or define set and get for o.